# how to pipe a merged stream to stdin of a spawned process?

Tags: node.js

I want to write a wrapper program to inject texts that it receive via websocket to the spawned process
I tried something like this

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const cmd = spawn(cmdname, {stdio:"inherit"})
// cmd.stdin is null
```

but I need `cmd.stdin` so I tried the following but it doesn't work I don't know what's wrong. for example for `cmdname=python3` it should act like a repl but it doesn't.

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const cmd = spawn(cmdname, {stdio:["pipe", 1, 2]})
process.stdin.pipe(cmd.stdin)

//var websocket = require('websocket-stream')
//var mergeStream = require('merge-stream')
//var wss = websocket.createServer({
//  perMessageDeflate: false,
//  port: opts.port
//}, handle)

//function handle(wstream) {
//  mergeStream(wstream,process.stdin).pipe(cmd.stdin);
//}
```

I didn't get to test the merge part because of the above problem.
my node version is `v8.6.0` if that's relevent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that I have to put `-i` in args

```
const cmd = spawn("python3",["-i"], {stdio:["pipe", 1, 2]})
```

and I didn't need to merge the stream.

here is the complete code: [replwrap](https://github.com/raoofha/replwrap/blob/master/replwrap.js)